# move git repository's .git folder to a different drive and create a symlink to that folder in the actual repository

Tags: git, symlink

Let's say, I have a git repository, that, after initialization, I've moved it's .git folder to a different drive/partition, then created a symlink (soft link) to that folder in it's original location. Will git normally use this .git symlink, or it will complain that it cannot use symlinks and will not work in such a way?
It's a Linux computer.

Comment: Is it on Linux, or is it Windows+NTFS soft/hard/junction links? Anyways, why dont you try? Creating a git local repo is like.. 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need a symlink.  After moving your `.git` directory, create a *file* named `.git` in your working copy with the content:

```
gitdir: /path/to/new/location/of/.git
```